# eu não estou conseguindo herde a classe cliente com uma das duas

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

eu crio um cliente que será PFísica como faço para  classe PFisica herde da classe cliente.

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,*lista,**D):
        self.codigo   = D.pop('cod','--')
        self.nome     = D.pop('n','--')
        self.fone     = D.pop('f','(--) ----- ----')
        self.data     = D.pop('d','--/--/----')
        self.Endereco = D.pop('end','--')
        self.Cidade   = D.pop('cid','--')
        self.UF       = D.pop('uf','--')
        self.tipo     = D.pop('t', 'PF ou PJ')
        self.cheques  = []
        for x in lista:
            self.cheques.append(x)
    def listaCheque(self):
        return self.cheques
    def adicionacheque(self,novocheque):
        if novocheque not in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.append(novocheque)
    def excluicheque(self,exccheque):
        if exccheque not in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.append(exccheque)


class PFisica:
    def __init__(self,**D):
        self.cliente = Cliente
        self.CPF     = D.pop('cpf','---.---.--- --')
        self.RG      = D.pop('rg','-.---.--- -')
    def getCliente(self):
        return self.cliente
    def emitirFicha(self):
        resposta='Nome: '+self.cliente+'\nCPF: '+self.CPF+'\nRG: '+self.RG+'\nEndereço: '+self.Endereco+'\nCidade: '+self.Cidade+'UF :'+self.UF
        return resposta
    
    
class PJuridica:
    def __init__(self,**D):
        self.cliente = Cliente
        self.CNPJ    = D.pop('cnpj','---.---.---/---- --')
        self.INSC    = D.pop('insc','--')
    def getCliente(self):
        return self.cliente
    def emitirFicha(self):
        resposta='Nome: '+self.cliente+'\nCNPJ: '+self.CNPJ+'\nEndereço: '+self.Endereco+'\nCidade: '+self.Cidade+'UF :'+self.UF
        return resposta
```

Comment: O que você entende por "associar"?

Comment: Você quer que PFisica **herde** de Cliente? Veja [aqui](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar com herança fica assim:
suas classes tem que herdar da classe base comum (cliente),  e chamar
os métodos da superclasse, usando a chamada especial `super()` - no
caso, o único método comum entre a base e as classes derivadas é
o `__init__` , então só ali precisamos usar o `super()`:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,*lista,**D):
        self.codigo   = D.pop('cod','--')
        self.nome     = D.pop('n','--')
        self.fone     = D.pop('f','(--) ----- ----')
        self.data     = D.pop('d','--/--/----')
        self.Endereco = D.pop('end','--')
        self.Cidade   = D.pop('cid','--')
        self.UF       = D.pop('uf','--')
        self.tipo     = D.pop('t', 'PF ou PJ')
        self.cheques  = []
        for x in lista:
            self.cheques.append(x)
            
    def listaCheque(self):
        return self.cheques
    def adicionacheque(self,novocheque):
        if novocheque not in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.append(novocheque)
    def excluicheque(self,exccheque):
        if exccheque not in self.cheques:
            self.cheques.append(exccheque)


class PFisica(Cliente):
    def __init__(self,**D):
        # extrair dos parâmetros "D" os dados específicos de pessoa física:
        self.CPF     = D.pop('cpf','---.---.--- --')
        self.RG      = D.pop('rg','-.---.--- -')
        # Chamar o __init__ de "cleinte" para completar a inicialização:
        super().__init__(**D)
        
        
    """    
    def getCliente(self):
        # Esse método não faz sentido: uma PFisica "é" um cliente, não tem como obter um cliente separado
        # a partir dela.
        return self.cliente
    """
    
    
    def emitirFicha(self): 
        ...
    
    
class PJuridica(Cliente):
    def __init__(self,**D):
        self.CNPJ    = D.pop('cnpj','---.---.---/---- --')
        self.INSC    = D.pop('insc','--')
        super().__init__(**D)

    def emitirFicha(self):
        resposta='Nome: '+self.cliente+'\nCNPJ: '+self.CNPJ+'\nEndereço: '+self.Endereco+'\nCidade: '+self.Cidade+'UF :'+self.UF
        return resposta
```